# Can a Knockout pureComputed work if it contains an observable that might not always exist?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Sorry if the question is poorly worded.

My problem is that I want to change an elements style based on a `pureComputed` but the computed contains an observable that may not always exist when the component is constructed, because the observable is from a different component and that component may not be constructed beforehand.

So I currently have something like this that I was hoping would be enough but doesn't work:

```
this.thingRunning = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    if(app.thing){
        return app.thing.running();
    }else{
        return false
    }
}, this);
```

So problem is that if `app.thing` is initially undefined then this computed always returns `false`. `app.thing` does get defined eventually, just not before the computed so I'm hoping that I can have the computed return true when it does.

I know this may be a problem with how my app is set up in general but I'm just wondering if there's an easy way around this that I'm missing as I'm still quite a noob at Knockout and JavaScript in general.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it definitely can!

However, with how things are structure right now you probably won't get a re-evaluation as you'd expect.

A better approach would be:

```
this.thingRunning = ko.pureComputed(function() {
    var app = ko.unwrap(app) || {},
        thing = ko.unwrap(app.thing) || {},
        running = ko.unwrap(thing.running);

    return ((typeof running == 'undefined' || running === null) ? false : running);
}, this);
```

Using this form, the dependencies of the `pureComputed` are very clear. More importantly they're properly registered, insofar that if any one of the three changes (and is one of the forms of `subscribable`) then this pureComputed will re-evaluate. It has the benefit of safely navigating the potentially non-existant values.

Here is a fully working example:

```js
function vm(){
 var self = this;
  
  self.thing = ko.observable({
   running: ko.observable(true)
  });
};

function otherVm(appModel){
 var self = this;
  
  self.appModel = appModel;
  
  self.thingRunning = ko.pureComputed(function(){
   var app = ko.unwrap(self.appModel) || {},
      thing = ko.unwrap(app.thing) || {},
        running = ko.unwrap(thing.running);
        
    return ((typeof running == 'undefined' || running === null) ? false : running);
  });
};

var app = new vm(); //try commenting this out
var other = new otherVm();

console.log(ko.unwrap(other.thingRunning));
```

Comment: This doesn't work for me. `thingRunning` still just returns false if `app.thing` is initially undefined.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. If `app`, `app.thing` are both observable's then it will recompute, as identified by the fiddle.

Comment: Sorry I should have been clearer, `app` and `app.thing` aren't observables. Only `app.thing.running` is an observable.